# Bring background process to foreground in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, background, foreground

I have been searching through internet to find how to bring a background process and just found how to do it from terminal, however I am trying to create my own shell in C and I would love to get some ideas on how to do this.
I want to, having the pid of the background process bring it to foreground using the function `waitpid()`.
Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

```
pid_t pid; //PID given by user
```

What I used for the command fg, which i made to execute programs in foreground, I used `waitpid(pid, NULL, 0)` after a `fork()`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the `SIGCONT` signal? see [man signal](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: I dont think that works for me, i want to bring a process with PID x which is in background to the foreground. SIGCONT just continues the process if it was stopped no?

Comment: Ok, in that you might want something like `xdotool` which allow to manipulate windows